# Referencing a variable in an object created using custom constructor

Tags: javascript

Trying to get this to work in JS:

```
var calculate = function(votesA, votesB, votesC) {

    var total = votesA + votesB + votesC;

    function Results(resultsA, resultsB, resultsC) {
        this.resultsA = resultsA;
        this.resultsB = resultsB;
        this.resultsC = resultsC;
    }

    var curResults = new Results(votesA, votesB, votesC);

    curResults.resultsA = (votesA / total) x 100;
    curResults.resultsB = (votesB / total) x 100;
    curResults.resultsC = (votesC / total) x 100;

    console.log(curResults.resultsA, curResults.resultsB, curResults.resultsC);
}

calculate(5,4,8);
calculate(5,6,8);
calculate(6,8,9);
```

Not sure why it isn't working, but I feel like it is something to do with how I am referencing the variables in curResults

Comment: can you tell us what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript's multiplication operator is `*`, not `x`.

The `x` in the following lines is giving you an "unexpected identifier" error:

```
curResults.resultsA = (votesA / total) x 100;
curResults.resultsB = (votesB / total) x 100;
curResults.resultsC = (votesC / total) x 100;
```

So change them to:

```
curResults.resultsA = (votesA / total) * 100;
curResults.resultsB = (votesB / total) * 100;
curResults.resultsC = (votesC / total) * 100;
```

> *Not sure why it isn't working, but I feel like it is something to do with how I am referencing the variables in* `curResults`

No, that part is fine. Though as an aside, there's no point in assigning `this.resultsA = resultsA;` (and `resultsB` and `C`) in your `Results()` constructor if you then immediately overwrite those values in the three lines above.

Comment: Feel like such an idiot haha thank you

Comment: It took me a few moments to spot it - at first I just naturally read each `x` as multiplication...